# How to remove out of stock product in cart page? Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1

Actually my need is, i have added some product to cart then after some months added product have out of stock position. That time delete my product from cart in magento 2. How is it?

I need to remove out of stock simple and configurable product in cart page Magento 2.

Based on login user and guest.

Comment: Cart page means after add to cart or your telling in detail or list page?

Comment: After add to cart.

Comment: Actually my need is, i have added some product to cart then after some months added product have out of stock position. That time delete my product from cart in magento 2. How is it?